# How to build Rebol 3 in MSVC

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I am trying to get Rebol 3 to compile in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, but so far I have been unsuccessful.  I am using a Git repo for my source which does not come with a solution.  I have tried creating a solution and manually importing all of the code files, but that does not work.  I really do not know what I am doing, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clone my repository: https://github.com/zsx/r3

Once you have cloned the repository, checkout the "atronix" branch (you're probably on it when you first cloned it), and initialize & update the submodule:

```
git clone https://github.com/zsx/r3.git
cd r3
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Open the ms vs solution file `make/msvc/r3.sln`

Edit:
  The old branch "msvc" is merged to "atronix", so use this one instead.

Comment: When I try to clone it, I only get one branch, called atronix.  It does not contain a solution.  If I download the repository as a zip, I can get the solution, but I don't know how to work with a repository that I have as a zip.  Any tips?

Comment: To checkout "msvc": `git checkout -b msvc -t origin/msvc`, assuming your "origin" points to my github repository

Comment: If you want to learn more about git, you can start with this tutorial: http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial

Comment: When I try to compile the solution, I get an error stating "Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\Owner\Source\Repos\r3-msvc\src\libffi\src\x86\win32.S'"

Comment: Could you check if the file exists on your system? if not, check if 'C:\Users\Owner\Source\Repos\r3-msvc\src\libffi' is empty.